# Having Trouble Installing Ubuntu on docker while using Synology NAS

Tags: server

I am having trouble installing Ubuntu on docker while using synology nas. Can someone help me with this request?

Comment: What is the disk format of the Synology NAS drive that you want to use?

Comment: {;ease read [ask] then [edit] your question with further detail